# Inserting into Azure Table in from Hadoop application

Tags: azure-table-storage

I have a hadoop application in which the mappers continuously insert many entries into a single Azure Table. Most of the entries have different partition key, so batch insertion may not be effective in this case. Because the Azure Table goes under a heavy pressure, I wonder to know whether it may become a bottleneck ? What is the downside of this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, many different partition keys is exactly the right way to increase throughput as it allows the service to spread out data more effectively. Batch is more intended for executing atomic operations than for significant increases in throughput. Batch can sometimes benefit throughput, and sometimes actually hurt since on the service it means a much longer operation as all the rows it specifies are gathers. Whether batching helps or not depends on network latency, batch size, and whether specific rows are in multiple concurrent batch requests, among other factors.

The main thing to consider for how partition keys are laid out is not insert but query. Point queries (one partition key and row key) are by far the fastest operation to execute on Azure storage and what we're optimized for. Spread out partition keys is great for this. The next most effective is partition queries (same partition key, multiple row keys). The slowest is table queries (multiple partitions). So, if you're intending to do a lot of non-point queries a spread out partition key could hurt you.

For more information read the table sections in the [performance and scalability document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-performance-checklist/#subheading27).